# How do I retrieve a list of key value pairs when using dynamic attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's assume I'm creating a product catalog in which I want to be able to dynamically create product attributes.  The data model I've defined looks like this:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :items
    has_many    :item_attributes

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :collection
    has_many :item_attribute_values

end

class ItemAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :collection
  has_many :item_attribute_values

end

class ItemAttributeValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_attribute
  belongs_to :item

end
```

The use case this is intended to support is one where various collections can exist, each with their own items.   A User can create custom attributes for each  collection.   The custom attributes are then populated by the user for each item in the collection.

An example:
For a collection of **Comic Books**, the attributes that will be tracked will be **Author** and **Inker**.   Item "Batman #1", will have 'Bob Kane' and 'John Doe' in the attribute values table.  Item "Spiderman #1", will have 'Stan Lee' and 'Jane Doe' in the attribute values table.

For a collection of **Cars**, the attributes that will be tracked will be **Year** and **Mileage**.   Item "Honda Civic", will have '2013' and '55000 Doe' in the attribute values table, etc, etc

If I wanted to list all the attribute key, value pairs associated with a specific item on a web page, what would be the best and most efficient way to retrieve them from the database?  Is there a better data model to support this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in similar cases is define a to_h() method in the classes that need this type of functionality

```
class Item
  def to_h
    item_attribute_values.reduce({}) do |m, iav|
      m[iav.name] = iav.value
      m
    end
  end
end
```

You can put this in a module and simply include it in your classes

Comment: I actually meant what's the best way to get all the info from the db.  I'll readjust the question.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may care, the answer actually ended up being an ActiveRecord question that looks something like this:

```
@item_details = Item.includes(collection: [{item_attributes: :item_attribute_values}]).find_by_id(@item.id)
```